# Not able to Download Excel file from the web with Python

Tags: python, excel, url, download, backend

I try to use Python to download excel "performance" file from: "https://www.amundietf.fr/fr/particuliers/produits/equity/amundi-msci-world-ucits-etf-eur-c/lu1681043599" but it seems the file is not on the webpage but is dynamically generated.
Does someone has an idea of how it is possible to download it ?

I went on the web to get some information but I couldn't solve the problem. I just understood that the problem arises because of the "dynamically generated" aspect of the file.